# Blog hosted on Google Cloud platform stopped working after changing VM from f1 to e2

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using a bitnami-wordpress-5-5-1-1-linux-debian-10-x86-64 image on a Google Cloud VM.

My blog at blog.stri.ml stopped working. I haven't touched the configuration in the last week. The last update that I have done was 10 days ago when I changed the VM from f1 to e2. It worked well until now.

The site is not accessible through external IP neither.
Content on Cloud Storage is accessible.
It is not a payment issue.

Has anyone faced a similar issue lately?

Thank you,
C.

Comment: Your question does not provide details which means we just guess. Two common problems are public IP address changed and the instance ran out of disk space.

Comment: Your site seems to be working fine. Are you actually still having a problem?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have increased the disk size and now it seems to be working again. I figured it out by inspecting the Mysql logs.